# Compare string to NSArray

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsmutablearray, compare

I have to classes the Checkin and the FriendList.

Checkin.h

```
@interface Checkin : NSObject {

    NSString *name;
    NSString *profID;
    NSString *place;
    NSString *photoURL;
    NSMutableArray *taggedID;
    NSMutableArray *taggedName;
```

and the Friendlist.h

```
@interface FriendList : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSString *profID;

}
```

What I am trying to do is to compare each checkin.profid(approximately 5-6) with the friendlist.h(200-5000).
I tried to do it with for loop but when checks the second checkin.profid is crashing.
This is my method:

```
  for(int i=0; i<[checkinArray count];i++){

     Checkin *tempcheck = [[Checkin alloc] init];
     tempcheck = [checkinArray objectAtIndex:i];

     for(int j=0;j<[friendsArray count]; j++){
         NSLog(@"count %d",j);
         FriendList *tempfriend = [[FriendList alloc] init];
         tempfriend  = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:j];

         if([tempcheck.profID isEqualToString:tempfriend.profID]){
             NSLog(@"Find prof id same for : %@",tempcheck.name);
             break;
         }
           else
             NSLog(@"Not found id same for: %@",tempcheck.name);
         [tempfriend release]; 
     }

    [tempcheck release];
   }
}
```

Is there any better way to do this comparison? Because its also too slow.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't going to be helping:

```
Checkin *tempcheck = [[Checkin alloc] init];
     tempcheck = [checkinArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

And

```
FriendList *tempfriend = [[FriendList alloc] init];
tempfriend  = [friendsArray objectAtIndex:j];
```

there's no reason to alloc them: just set it to be the object at the desired index:

```
Checkin *tempcheck = [checkinArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

would be better. As for doing the finds, why not loop through the checkins and for each checkin.profId instantiate a new NSPredicate to find the profId through the friendlist. Try [NSPredicate filterWithFormat:@"(profId = %@)"];

and then use filteredArrayUsingPredicate on your array.

Comment: something like this one? NSString *tempProfID = @"123456"    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"profID == %@", ];     NSArray *results = [directoryContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Answer (score 1):

Your memory management is all broken. When you do something like this:

```
 Checkin *tempcheck = [[Checkin alloc] init];
 tempcheck = [checkinArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

What you are doing is creating an object and then assigning the pointer to the object in the checkin array. This causes a memory leak right there.

Then, later on when you do:

```
[tempcheck release];
```

you're actaully calling release on the object in the array, not the one you alloc'd earlier. This presumably leads the the object in the array being garbage-collected and then when you try and access it the second time round you get a crash.

Remove the allocs & releases and just do something like this:

```
Checkin *tempcheck = [checkinArray objectAtIndex:i];
```